# Using Flex Layout within Angular [innerHTML]

Tags: html, angular, data-binding, innerhtml, angular-flex-layout

I'm attempting to use [Angular Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) within innerHTML, but the result is not being rendered in the browser correctly. I know routing doesn't work within innerHTML due its use of Angular bindings so this might be the same thing?, but I can't find documentation on this specific use casee anywhere. My expectation was that Flex Layout should work since other grid systems such as *Bootstrap* seem to render correctly.

Side note: I understand that Bootstrap works since it applies classes, but I would like to use Flex Layout since I'm already using Flex layout in other places within my project.

HTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="myFlexLayout | safeHtml"></div> <!-- safeHtml is a pipe that uses bypassSecurityTrustHtml -->
```

TS:

```
this.myFlexLayout =  '<div fxFlex="75" fxLayout="row">
    <div fxFlex="50">col 1</div>
    <div fxFlex="50">col 2</div>
  </div>'
```

RESULT: Gets rendered without flexbox applied (i.e. fxflex instead of fxFlex and no styling is applied):

```
<div fxflex="75" fxlayout="row">
  <div fxflex="50">col 1</div>
  <div fxflex="50">col 2</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to render flexbox layouts within innerHtml?

Let me know if you have any thoughts!

Comment: I'm not sure whether writing Angular directives directly inside innerHTML is supposed to work, but I guess you could just use simple CSS classes to apply these styles as a workaround. You're talking of Bootstrap, maybe it works because Bootstrap grid system is just about CSS classes.

Comment: @bmartins yea I think that's the way to go!

Comment: Depending your use case and design you can achieve desired behavior by using content projection or partial templates. innerHTML won't work because `fxFlex` is an angular directive and it needs to go over compilation process.